# How does this code work? (GDI, C#)

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

I was just wondering if anyone could shed some light onto this for me. I've been coding c# for years but never even touched anything in the System.Drawing namespace except for the bitmap class and I've been following some tutorials and came up with some code that works. I'm developing a 2D Game Engine and the code below is for the graphics engine, which uses GDI. However, I just don't understand how this code is even working. Here it is:

```
    private Graphics frontBuffer;
    private Graphics backBuffer;
    private Bitmap backBufferBitmap;

    public void Initialize()
    {
      backBufferBitmap = new Bitmap(game.Form.Width, game.Form.Height);
      frontBuffer = game.Form.CreateGraphics();
      backBuffer = Graphics.FromImage(backBufferBitmap);          
    }

    public void Update()
    {
      try
      {
        frontBuffer.DrawImageUnscaled(backBufferBitmap,0,0);
        backBuffer.Clear(Color.Black);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        throw e;
      }
    }
```

So, the main part that's confusing to me is this;

How is the back buffer bitmap getting updated? and why is the back buffer being cleared and not the front buffer?

Also, the initialize method is called once and the update method is called once per frame in a while loop.

Comment: Just for the record: I have some doubts about the code you found or wrote as `game.Form.CreateGraphics();` usually is a bad idea as is buffering the Graphics object.

Comment: But why? All I'm doing really is referencing the forms graphics object?

Comment: There is no such thing. You are (sic!) creating one. But you shouldn't. It is up the the `Paint` event to do that! (Unless you need one elsewhere because you want to measure things or want to draw __non-persistent__ graphics like a rubber-band line..) - Also: The Frontbuffer is cleared implicitly as it contains nothing when you create its bitmap.

Comment: I've disabled the paint event because using this method is faster. All I'm really doing is calling the paint event when it's needed, instead of every frame. Without this approach, the engine just wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: You did DoubleBuffer the form? Does your form persist a minimize-maximize cycle?

Comment: yeS it's double buffered, even though there's no need because I'm drawing to a bitmap that's the size of the control and I haven't implementing maximizing or minimizing.

Comment: That is not relevant, just an exaple; other system events will mess with the graphics as well. .And the code you show __does__ draw onto the Form (`frontBuffer.DrawImageUnscaled(backBufferBitmap,0,0);`).

Comment: Yes but I'm drawing to the back buffer, which draws to the bitmap. I'm aware that there are issues, but until I stumble upon them I can't fix them.

Comment: Also, regardless of any issues the entire graphics engine needs to rely on this method

Comment: _Yes but I'm drawing to the back buffer_ No, you draw from a bitmap to the frontBuffer which is pointing to the Form surface.  A Graphics object can be seenn as a port into some bitmap: either related to a memory Bitmap or the the pixels of a control surface. You use both ways. - Be that as it may, if you are happy with the results go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you initialize the `backBuffer` graphics objects from the bitmap, every time you say, for example `backBuffer.DrawLine(...)` GDI+ will do the pixel manipulations directly on this Bitmap. They are linked in a way. Think of `backBufferBitmap` as the canvas, and of `backBuffer` as the brush.

The `frontBuffer` is initialized from the form instead. So the form is it's canvas and whatever you do with `frontBuffer` is drawn to the form - in this case here it draws the `backBufferBitmap`.

It's basically a double-buffering scheme, that has a lot of advantages over directly drawing your lines and circles to the form, e.g. less flickering. Whenever you draw something to a form, remember that it is removed very often (e.g. when you move the form outside of the screen area). You would need to refresh it using the form's `Paint` event.

After `Update()` is called, you would need to redraw your scene to `backBuffer`, before you call Update again, because the bitmap is blacked out by your `Clear()` after it is drawn to the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very informative. I've realised the main reason I was confused is being I didn't know that after I initialized the backbuffer I didn't know it would draw specifically to the bitmap. Thank you for clearing this up. I had a feel that's what was going on on, but i wasn't sure. Just so you know, I'm not using the paint event and I'm instead using my own methods by calling Application.DoEvents each frame. Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems like you are happy with this answer @MathewO'Dwyer ? If so please mark it as accepted so other can find the right answer quickly if they are searching for help in the same area and also to give credit to Jens.

Comment: @FSDaniel Okay, first time doing this sorry :).

Comment: @FSDaniel how should I go about giving credit to jens?

Comment: No problem. See you figured it out :) Just accepting his answer gives him points.

Answer (score 0):

`frontBuffer` is getting updated because each time you are calling `frontBuffer.DrawImageUnscaled(backBufferBitmap,0,0);` in `update()`

`backBuffer` is gettting cleared because you are calling `backBuffer.Clear(Color.Black);`

Also, `initialize()` is supposed to be called only once. At the time of object creation. And I believe it is part of a larger program where parent is calling `update()` of child.

Comment: are you sure that was your doubt?

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. However, Initialize and Update are my own methods that I created. What I don't understand is how the bitmap is being updated?

Comment: Also what I meant was why am I calling backBuffer.clear instead of frontBuffer.clear ? Why do I have to do that?

Comment: if `backBufferBitmap` is getting updated, then you are calling initialize() more than once.

Comment: Then nothing is currently updating it and you should just be getting a black screen.

Comment: Can you share the method where you are using it's instance?

Comment: Let me elaborate more. I know that this code works fine. I draw to the back buffer, and it shows up on the form. Which is exactly what I want to happen. The issue is that I don't understand how the above code works and what it's doing/why it's doing what it does

Comment: In the constructor of the winform form, I called Initialize, then I set up a while loop and call update, I also make sure the form is shown and focused. that's literally all there is it too it.